# Dynamic Sidebars: Else statements with Wordpress Widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, widget

My site is set up to show a specific widget based on the page. What I want it to do is show a specific widget based on one category. My current code partially works: it shows the widget based on the category, but it also shows the widget that should only populate if the user is viewing another page. Here is my code:

```
<div id="banner">
<?php if ( is_category( 'dogs' ) || !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Top Dogs") ) : ?>
<?php elseif ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Cats") ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: You know that ! means "does not"?

Comment: Yes. This code works except for the "elseif," which displays the "Cats" sidebar even if on the Dog page.

Comment: I think, you should give condition like is_page("Dog") instead of is_category()

Comment: Have you tried this with an "else" statement instead of "elseif", because I've never seen elseif used without an else after (if, elseif, else or if, else).

Comment: Removing "if" generates a Parse Error. The problem I'm having is that that both widgets show up when I only want one to show up if the user is viewing that category.

Comment: Using is_page will not work because this is a category archive, not a general WordPress page.